# Web site certificate has expired only via WGET/CURL

Tags: ssl, certificate

My website uses a Let's Encrypt cert that works fine using a web browser.  When retrieving a file from my website via wget/curl I receive a warning that the SSL cert has expired.  So I have created a simple script to check my SSL cert on my side:

```
[root]# cat certinfo.sh
 nslookup $1
  (openssl s_client -showcerts -servername $1 -connect $1:443 <<< "Q" | openssl x509 -text | grep -iA2 "Validity")
```

I then run the script against my site:

```
[root]# ./certinfo.sh files.mysite.io
Server:         172.31.254.4
Address:        172.31.254.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   files.mysite.io
Address: 52.204.19.216

depth=3 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
DONE
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec  1 04:00:19 2021 GMT
            Not After : Mar  1 04:00:18 2022 GMT
```

What exactly is going here?  Today (Dec 14 2021) is in the range of the certificate validity as shown above.  Yet there is a "notAfter" setting that has expired.  I can't find that "notAfter" in my certificate or in the intermediate certificates.

Where is this coming from, and how do I fit it?

Comment: **It's LetsEncrypt** which by default still provides a chain to, as the error message says, DST Root CA X3 -- which expired on Sept. 30. _Most_ clients like browsers can substitute the newer, valid ISRG X1 root, but programs **using OpenSSL 1.0.2** fail if _both_ roots (DST and ISRG) are still configured, which depends on your system; whether curl and wget use OpenSSL (and which version) also depends on your system. There were _dozens_ of Qs about this in the week or two after Sept. 30 -- search for the ones appropriate to your system. Use newer OpenSSL, remove DST root, or change the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave is correct, and as it's a server issue, the best option would be changing your certificate on server:
https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/